# iOS layout: How to keep a button in the middle an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextfield

I have an image that needs a UITextField in the middle of it at all times. However, I can't get it do what I want.

I pinned the image with top, left and right constraint and gave it a height constraint. I put the UITextField in the middle of the image and tried various methods to keep it in the middle, but they all keep failing. Any tips are appreciated. Here is what the image currently looks like. First one iPhone 4 and second one is iPhone 6

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the image view and the button and create two constraints: a “Horizontal Centers” constraint and a “Vertical Centers” constraint. Neither view has to be a subview of the other, and they don't have to be in the same superview either.

Here's a demo. I've already constrained the image view to fill the top left quadrant of the root view, and I've dragged in a button. In the demo I'll select the image view and the button (hold shift to select multiple views) and create the two centering constraints. Then I'll use the Preview assistant to show that the button stays centered when the image view's frame changes.

[image: demo of centering constraints]

Comment: Wow, this was great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do:

- Embed the `UIImageView` and `UITextField` inside a `UIView`.
- Set constraints of `UIImageView` leading, trailing, top, and bottom to `UIView` with constant of 0.
- Set constraints of `UITextField` center horizontally with container view, and center vertically with container view.

Then it's up to you on where you want to position that `UIView`. This will definitely always position the `UITextField` to the center of `UIImageView`.

Comment: Since OP only has an imageView, I think the embedding is unnecessary though, just position wherever he/she wants then give a horizontal + vertical centered constraint

Comment: @Happiehappie I agree.